# Arduino servo struct "does not name a type"

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, arduino

I'm trying to run an arduino program that uses a struct containing servo objects and it gives me this error:

```
error: 'leg' does not name a type
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with memory management but I'm fairly new to this so any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
#include <Servo.h> 

typedef struct{
 Servo hip;
 Servo shin;
 Servo foot;
}leg;



int currentPin = 0; //this is the pin that the leg will be attached to


leg getLeg(void){
  leg newLeg;
  newLeg.hip.attach(currentPin++);
  newLeg.shin.attach(currentPin++);
  newLeg.foot.attach(currentPin++);

  return newLeg;  

}

void setup() 
{ 
  leg frontLeft = getLeg();
  leg frontRight = getLeg();
  leg backRight = getLeg();
  leg backLeft = getLeg();
} 


void loop() 
{ 


}
```

Comment: where is the 'struct_Name' appear?

Comment: I was trying to generalise the error, it should be clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
struct legtype {
    Servo hip;
    Servo shin;
    Servo foot;
};

typedef legtype leg;
```

Does that work?

Cheers,

Comment: You've tagged the question with 'C' - is it really so or are compiling as C++? In any case, why `typedef` the `struct` instead of just using `struct leg newLeg;`?

Comment: Yes Its C, I only know C and I've been fine so far. Unless.. could it be C++?

Comment: Ok I've fixed it by using struct leg. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes... Have a look at this SO thread explaining the intricacies of `typedef`'s in C and C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Answer (score 2):

defining the struct in a header file solved this for me.
In arduino make a new tab named : "`whatever.h`"
define the struct in whatever.h
include whatever.h in the main file.

Comment: Only option that worked for me. But I don't understand why the struct-typedef must be in a separate header file. By the way, I use Arduino for ESP8266.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I don't get it either.